# Can castles windsor container return the same instance of a component implementing 2 interfaces

Tags: castle-windsor

Is is possible with the Castle Windsor Container to have one component implement two different interfaces and then when resolving it to return the same component instance?  For example;

```
var windsor = new WindsorContainer()
    .AddComponent<InterfaceA, ClassAB>()
    .AddComponent<InterfaceB, ClassAB>();

var classAB1 = windsor.Resolve<InterfaceA>();
var classAB2 = windsor.Resolve<InterfaceB>();

Assert.AreSame(classAB1, classAB2);
```

If I try this as shown I get an exception with the message *There is a component already registered for the given key*, if I provide different keys then it returns two separate instances of the class `ClassAB`.

Edit:  Ideally I would like to do this in a config file.

Comment: Question added to the Windsor FAQ: http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/FAQ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[TestFixture]
public class Forwarding {
    public interface InterfaceA {}

    public interface InterfaceB {}

    public class ClassAB: InterfaceA, InterfaceB {}

    [Test]
    public void tt() {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>().ImplementedBy<ClassAB>());
        var a = container.Resolve<InterfaceA>();
        var b = container.Resolve<InterfaceB>();
        Assert.AreSame(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh son of a b... really?  You can do that? Lord knows the workarounds I've come up with.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, this looks great but just to move the goal posts do you know if this is also possible to do in a config file?

Answer (score 1):

I know one solution to this - it can be done like so:

```
var someInstance = new Instance();
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IFirstInterface)).Instance(someInstance));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ISecondInterface)).Instance(someInstance));
```

... but then you lose the container's ability to instantiate the `Instance` class, so its dependencies will not be automagically resolved. Of course, if your instance does not have any dependencies, you probably don't care about this.